# How we identify that "previous active class is left or right" when displaySubMenu call on click link

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul id="menu-controls">
<li><a target="_self" onclick="return displaySubMenu(0);" id="menu-controls-0" href="" class=""><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a target="_self" onclick="return displaySubMenu(1);" id="menu-controls-1" href="" class=""><span>Oleg Test</span></a></li>
<li><a target="_self" onclick="return displaySubMenu(2);" id="menu-controls-2" href="" class="act"><span>Products</span></a></li>
<li><a class="active" onclick="return displaySubMenu(3);"target="_self" ><span>About Us</span></a> </li>
<li><a class="" onclick="return displaySubMenu(4);"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
<li><a class="" onclick="return displaySubMenu(5);" class=""><span>Login / Register</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

How we identify that "previous active class is left or right" when displaySubMenu call on click link?

Need to check "active" class is left or right in display menu function?

Comment: Please elaborate your question with some more code or a Fiddle of what you wish to achieve..

Comment: Need to check "active" class is left or right in displaySubMenu function call?

Comment: Can you please provide the JS of displaySubMenu function or explain what exactly you mean by "left or right" in this context??

Comment: nothing in displaySubMenu function it's new function

Comment: Then what do you mean by left or right??? Are they classes given to any fields??

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have a navigation menu where you wish to check the previously active class (or currently active class) on click of an anchor??

Comment: no when i click on menu then prpreviously active class is left or right from current click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.index()` to determine position of your `a.active` :

```
$("#menu-controls li a").click(function () {

    var myActive = $("a.active").parent().index();
    var myClicked = $(this).parent().index()

    if (myActive < myClicked) {
        alert("Previous active was left")
    } else if (myActive > myClicked) {
        alert("Previous active was right")
    } else if (myActive == myClicked) {
        alert("Previous active is this clicked one")
    }

    $("a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active")

})
```

Check the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BmD2/)

Comment: Nice fiddle, I didn't knew that .index(), it's awesome ^^ +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I've understood your question correctly but if I'm right, try this.. Give a generic class(for eg. "items") to each of the anchor tags.. Now in the displaySubMenu function use this->

```
var flag = 0;
var th = $(this);
$(th).parent().find('.items').each(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('left');
   $(this).removeClass('right');
   if(flag == 1){
      $(this).addClass('right');
   } else
   if($(this) == $(th) {
      flag = 1;
   } else {
      $(this).addClass('left');
});
if($(th).parent().find('.active').hasClass('left')){
   console.log("Left"); // Write your code here for the case where previously active is left
   $(this).removeClass('active');
} else if($(th).parent().find('.active').hasClass('right')){
   console.log("Right"); // Write your code here for the case where previously active is right
   $(this).removeClass('active');
}

$(th).addClass('active');
```

In this code, I'm simply traversing the anchor tags one by one and all the tags before the currently clicked element are given the class left and those after it are given the class right by using a flag (As those tags written before the currently clicked tag shall be in it's left and vice-versa). Now it is checked if the previously active class has the class left or right and then we add the class active to the currently clicked tag after removing it from the previous tag..

Comment: this is not exactly same output but this near to my expected outcome...........Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cgd6w/) that log if the active element is before or after the clicked one.

Change on HTML : new param in the function 'this'

```
<ul id="menu-controls">
<li><a target="_self" onclick="return displaySubMenu(0, this);" id="menu-controls-0" href="" class=""><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a target="_self" onclick="return displaySubMenu(1, this);" id="menu-controls-1" href="" class=""><span>Oleg Test</span></a></li>
<li><a target="_self" onclick="return displaySubMenu(2, this);" id="menu-controls-2" href="" class="act"><span>Products</span></a></li>
<li><a class="" onclick="return displaySubMenu(3, this);"target="_self" ><span>About Us</span></a> </li>
<li><a class="active" onclick="return displaySubMenu(4, this);"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
<li><a class="" onclick="return displaySubMenu(5, this);" class=""><span>Login / Register</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

the JQUERY :

```
function displaySubMenu(number, element){
    var lastActive = $('.active').parents('li');
    var currentClick = $(element).parents('li');
    console.log(lastActive);console.log(currentClick);
    if($(currentClick).next(lastActive).length){
        var lastPosition = 'right';
    } else {
        var lastPosition = 'left';
    }
    console.log(lastPosition);
}
```